# Change text color depending on the status

Tags: php

I want to change the color of the status which are (Pending, Approved and Cancelled) dynamically.

so far I here's my code but the color didn't change. Any Suggestion? thanks in advance

```
if ($status == 'Approved' )
                            echo 'style="color: green;"';
                        else if ($status == 'Cancelled' )
                            echo 'style="color: red;"';
                        else if ($status == 'Pending' )
                            echo 'style="color: blue;"';

                        echo '>'.$row['status'].'</th>';
```

Comment: if ($status == 'Approved' )
                                echo 'style="color: green;"';
                            else if ($status == 'Cancelled' )
                                echo 'style="color: red;"';
                            else if ($status == 'Pending' )
                                echo 'style="color: blue;"';
    
                            echo '>'.$row['status'].'</th>';

Comment: This my code so far

Comment: alright. sorry for that

Comment: can we get a sample of the html output as well?

Comment: Are you sure you want to print that in the head of the table, and not just as a normal table row?

Comment: the text color of my output is still black.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this ? And Maybe there could be Capital letter problem in "==" Operator, for example if you defined $status = 'approved'; it's not show with green. It has to be $status = 'Approved'

```
<?php 
                            if ($status == 'Approved' )
                                $whatscolor = 'color: green';
                            else if ($status == 'Cancelled' )
                                $whatscolor = 'color: red';
                            else if ($status == 'Pending' )
                                $whatscolor = 'color: blue';
    ?>

    <div style="<?php echo $whatscolor; ?>"><?php echo $row['status']; ?></div></th>
```

But if you want to change all web page's text color you can do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<?php
    //$status = "Pending"; it has to be defined before here.
    if ($status == 'Approved' )
        $whatscolor = 'color: green';
    else if ($status == 'Cancelled' )
        $whatscolor = 'color: red';
    else if ($status == 'Pending' )
        $whatscolor = 'color: blue';
?>
<style>
body {
    <?php echo $whatscolor; ?>
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
Content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tought you want to change only $row['status'] 's color. If you want to do this this solution will help you. But you're searching something else I'll try to help anyway.

Comment: I want to change the text color depending on the status.

Comment: I add other option

Answer (score 0):

I will give you alternative,

```
<?php $row['status'] = "Approved"; ?>
<div style="width: 100px;height:100px;display: block;border: 1px solid;<?php if ($status == 'Approved') { echo 'color: green;"'; } else if ($status == 'Cancelled') { echo 'color: red'; } else if ( $status == 'Pending') { echo 'color: blue;'; } echo '">' . $row['status'] . '</div>';
```

Check this, its working code.